# pipe python3 output into dzen2

Tags: python, linux, pipe

i try to pipe some output from python3 in to dzen2, but dzen wont update.

in bash:

```
i=0; while true; do; echo $i; (( i++ )); sleep 1; done | dzen2
```

output terminal:

```
0
1
2
3...
```

in python

```
import time
i=0
while True:
  print(i)
  i+=1
  time.sleep(1)
```

output terminal:

```
0
1
2
3...
```

python3 while.py | dzen2
black empty dzen2-bar

bash-loop.sh | dzen2
black bar which counts from 0 to ...

Comment: Buffering.  Buffering.  Buffering.

Comment: When python's output is to a tty, it line buffers stdout.  But when its output is a pipe, stdout is block buffered.  This means that python is holding all the data until it has a full block (1024 bytes, or 512, or 4192, depending on your system) to write.  This is very standard.  See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/107705/python-output-buffering

Comment: @WilliamPursell: Please convert the comment to an answer.

Answer (score 1):

When python's output is to a tty, it line buffers stdout. But when its output is a pipe, stdout is block buffered. This means that python is holding all the data until it has a full block (1024 bytes, or 512, or 4192, depending on your system) to write. This is very standard. See: stackoverflow.com/questions/107705/python-output-buffering